# Mentioning version number

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: *[Restore PostgreSQL database using only the tablespace files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57360575/restore-postgresql-database-using-only-the-tablespace-files)*

When I wrote the question, the help suggested not mentioning version number of PostgreSQL. However the PostgreSQL topic itself says to mention the version number.  Which is best?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tag wiki trumps the general help text in this case because it is more specific.

The tag wiki description mentioning that a specific version is expected means that answers may vary wildly between versions, and the users frequenting this tag had had to ask users often what version they use.

As a general rule, specific instructions written in a tag's description with regards to what information is needed in questions is likely to be more accurate for questions of that tag.